# Ещё раз: "не" с глаголами

Tags: грамматика

А глаголы "нехватать", "недоставать"? Если вместе - одно понятие, а если раздельно - другое. Хотя, кажется, теперь пишут во всех случаях раздельно. Можно ли это уточнить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приставка "недо-" в глаголах обозначает "несоответствие норме": Мне недостает пяти рублей до необходимой суммы. Такие глаголы надо отличать от глаголов с частицей "не" в значении "отсутствие действия": Во время войны люди недоедали, недосыпали. - Ребенок капризничал и не доел кашу (не совершил действия)

Answer (score 3):

Не хватать - всегда раздельно. Недостает или не достает - зависит от значения. Денег недостает- слитно, приставка недо-.   Малыш не достает до стола - раздельно.

Comment: @Алена7, я кликнул @виктор1799, наверное, потому, что он оказался более многословным. Поэтому примите мою простую благодарность за ответ.